# Customizing Robotframework reports

Tags: robotframework

I tried to use the project [RoboReport](https://github.com/vvkalkundri/RoboReport). when i am trying to run the steps to generate HTML report as given in the link .

> python robo_report.py

i get the below error .

> 'robo_report.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just a documentation bug. The correct command should be:

```
python robo_graph.py
```

Comment: thank you @Helio  . i tried the python robo_graph.py, now i am getting error on plotly.  _> import plotly
ImportError: No module named plotly_   ..  i see i already have Name: plotly
Version: 2.2.1

Comment: Maybe is missing other requirements. Try, `pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vvkalkundri/RoboReport/master/requirements.txt`

Comment: yes, i figured, the virtualenv was not set up right. Once that was fixed, i no longer get the error. thanks for taking a look at my issue. appreciate.

Comment: now the reports are not generated. i run into below error .  `(roboreport) <Laptop>:RoboReport <name>$ python robo_graph.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robo_graph.py", line 70, in <module>
    robo_graph_generator()
  File "robo_graph.py", line 61, in robo_graph_generator
    html_data = create_chart(overall_result,tag_results)
  File "/Users/<name>/RoboReport/chart.py", line 73, in create_chart
    passed_values.append(tag_results[tags]['pass'])
KeyError: 'pass'`